# Windows Bootable Flash Drive & ISO Image

Tags: windows, windows-10, iso-image, bootable-media

I have a new Windows 10 laptop on which it has a recovery partition. Do I need to create a bootable drive using USB in spite of having a recovery partition?

The second question is, can I create an image of Windows of the current setup and in future, if anything goes wrong, I reinstate the image on my laptop to have a fresh Windows installation?

Which approach is better?

Appreciate any insight on this?

Comment: We could boot into recovery mode or create a bootable USB disk. Both is helpful for repair system. We should create system image before corruption occur. So create it now to avoid risk in the feature. At least it will keeps your system configuration at a specific point. But fresh Windows installation will remove every thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can reach recovery partition via boot menu. Also you can login there via bootable media in case your boot partition is broken.

You can create snapshot of your disk and store it on safe place. But to avoid open/lock file it's better to use live CD/flash to run some Linux or Live Windows.

To say which one is better is a bit personal opinion. I prefer to make regular backup of important files and do new installation.